# Is it true that comparison is slower than type casting, and boxing is even slower?

Tags: c#, casting, comparison

I heard about that `type casting` is slow. I had thought `comparison` is fast, but...

It seems `IComparable.CompareTo(object y)` has to use the `cast`, which would make `x > y` at least as slow as `y as MyClass` if not slower if there is no `IComparable<T>` available.

So, am I right to say that:

It is always better to implement `IComparable<T>` than `IComparable` because then we don't have to type cast?

#### Update

Is `boxing` much slower than type casting between 2 reference types?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: "I heard about that type casting is slow." - Where did you hear that? Please link to the source. Without the context we can't tell what's going on.

Comment: Slow is relative. Perhaps if you did tens of thousands at a time you'd notice the difference. Just use what fits the situation best.

Answer (score 1):

From a performance standpoint it's always better to implement the generic versions of these interfaces because it's a guarantee that you will avoid the [boxing of value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx), which is the #1 performance killer in this type of scenario.

It is also the case that the generic versions will also not need to make runtime type checks, but the performance hit from these checks is very smaller than that from boxing and will be much harder to notice in practice.

Seeing as there's nothing you lose by implementing `IComparable<T>` then the conclusion it's clear: you should always do it, as there's nothing to lose and potentially quite a bit to gain.

Comment: `un/boxing` is a value type cast to reference type vice versa. So shouldn't `boxing` have similar performance as `as`?

Comment: @colinfang: Not necessarily. It's not too hard to write code that causes extra boxing at the `CompareTo` call site, e.g. comparing with `i` inside a loop where `i` is an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

It's always better implement generics. Not only for performance, also because you get compile time checking.